# Robotium automation using genymotion

Tags: robotium, genymotion

Im new to robotium. can any one please help me in developing a automation script using genymotion. I have tried executing the script on default android emulator. but i want it to run on genymotion emulator. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As Genymotion behaves like a real device plugged through USB, your tests should work perfectly fine on Genymotion as on the emulator.

If you have a specific problem feel free to precise it.